# Como animar el cambio de tamaño de un div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition

Hice un componente en react que muestra parte de un texto, y con un boton "Ver Mas", el texto pasa a verse completo. Mi pregunta es, como puedo lograr que el cambio se haga mediante una transicion, y no sea un salto abrupto?
Intente poner `transition: .3s ease all` en algunos selectores pero no surtio efecto.
Dejo un codepen y mi codigo, por si alguien puede ayudarme.

> **Codepen** https://codepen.io/mani-guerra/pen/mdXZXaP

**Mi componente:**

```
const Componente = () => {
  const [view, setView] = useState(false)
  return(
    <>
      <div className={`full-description-container ${view ? "open" : "closed"}`}>
        <p className="full-description">
           // Aca va un texto largo
           </p>
       {!view && <div className="shadow" />}
       </div>
       {!view &&
        <button
          alt="See full description"
          className="read-more-button"
          onClick={() => setView(!view)}
        >
          Read more
        </button>}
     </>
  );
}
```

Y este es mi CSS

```
 .full-description-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 50vw;
    overflow: hidden;

    &.open{
      height: 100%;
      transition: .4s ease all; /* Esto no me está sirviendo */
    }

    .shadow{
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
      background: linear-gradient(356.3deg, #FFFFFF 28.22%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99.34%);
    }
  }

  .read-more-button{
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: green;
    font-size: 16px;
    
    transform: translateY(30px);
    transition: .4s ease all;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que no puedo aplicar una transicion a un `height` que no  sea fijo. No funciona en porcentajes ni en `auto`. Entonces la solucion es usar un `max-height` en ambos casos, y cuando el contenido está desplegado, darle un `max-height` lo suficientemente alto como para que no quede chico nunca. En mi caso con 2000px estoy sobrado para cualquier resolucion.

```
.full-description-container{
    position: relative;
    max-height: 150px;
    width: 50vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .4s ease max-height;

    &.open{
      max-height: 2000;
      transition: .4s ease max-height;
    }
```